# How to stop label from adding results each time a button is clicked

Tags: c#, xcode, while-loop, label

I am working on a project for school. I have to create and SQL statement and then use a while loop to input information into a label. Every thing is working correctly except when you search for a new item, the label still displays the result from the last search. [Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNDZv.png) [Second Result Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjcvv.png)
Any way to fix this?

Comment: Would be better to put code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the label's text before you start looping.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the label text first then show the result on it.
label1.text="";

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear before start a new loop.
Try this:

```
Nameofyourlabel.Text = "";
```